# @ngrx 4 store return type

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I am creating a web app using Angular 4 and @ngrx 4 and I am having a problem with the `Store` return type. This is the component in which I am using the `Store`:

```
export class ProductEditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  categoryMap: Map<number, Node>;
  categoryObs$: Observable<State>;
  categoryObsSubscription;

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Retrieve data from the backend.
    this.categoryObs$ = this.store.select('productTree');
    this.categoryObsSubscription = this.categoryObs$.subscribe((res: State) => {
      this.categoryMap = res.productTree;
    }, (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });

    this.store.dispatch(new productTreeActions.LoadProductTreeAction(1));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.categoryObsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

From what I could understand of the documentation, the observer that I get from `store.select` should be typed to the `State` interface, since I created the `Store` as: `store: Store<State>`

However when I try to assign my observable to the selected `Store` (`this.categoryObs$ = this.store.select('productTree');`), I get this error:

```
Type 'Store<Map<number, Node>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<State>'. Types of property 'operator' are incompatible. Type 'Operator<any, Map<number, Node>>' is not assignable to type 'Operator<any, State>'. Type 'Map<number, Node>' is not assignable to type 'State'. Property 'productTree' is missing in type 'Map<number, Node>'.
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, since I have checked the value of `res` and it corresponds to the `State` class.

Here is my redux:

```
export interface State {
  productTree: Map<number, Node>;
  errorMsg: string;
}

const initialState: State = {
  productTree: new Map<number, Node>(),
  errorMsg: ''
};

export function productTreeReducer(state = initialState, action: productTreeOperations.Actions): State {

  switch (action.type) {
    case productTreeOperations.LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE:
      return initialState; // Reset state

    case productTreeOperations.LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE_COMPLETE:
      return { productTree: action.payload, errorMsg: '' };

    case productTreeOperations.LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE_FAIL:
      return { productTree: undefined, errorMsg: action.payload }

    case productTreeOperations.DELETE_BRANCH:
      return deleteBranch(action.payload, state);

    case productTreeOperations.ADD_CHILD:
      return addChild(action.payload.parent, action.payload.newChild, state);

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And actions:

```
export const LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE = 'load-product-tree';
export const LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE_COMPLETE = 'load-product-tree-complete';
export const LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE_FAIL = 'load-product-tree-fail';

export const DELETE_BRANCH = 'delete-branch';
export const ADD_CHILD = 'add-child';

/**
 * Loads tree from backend and resets current state.
 */
export class LoadProductTreeAction implements Action {
  readonly type = LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE;
  constructor (public payload: number) { }
}

/**
 * Returns the loaded tree from the backend.
 */
export class LoadProductTreeCompleteAction implements Action {
  readonly type = LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE_COMPLETE;
  constructor (public payload: Map<number, Node>) { }
}

/**
 * Returns an error that happened when the tree was being loaded from the backend.
 */
export class LoadProductTreeFailAction implements Action {
  readonly type = LOAD_PRODUCT_TREE_FAIL;
  constructor (public payload: string) { }
}

/**
 * Deletes an entire branch of the tree (the current node and all child nodes).
 */
export class DeleteBranchAction implements Action {
  readonly type = DELETE_BRANCH;
  constructor (public payload: Node) { }
}

/**
 * Adds a child to a node.
 */
export class AddChildAction implements Action {
  readonly type = ADD_CHILD;
  constructor (public payload: { parent: Node, newChild: Node }) { }
}

export type Actions = LoadProductTreeAction |
                      LoadProductTreeCompleteAction |
                      LoadProductTreeFailAction |
                      DeleteBranchAction |
                      AddChildAction;
```

Comment: Take my advice, read some more about store and specially take a look at example apps before continuing!

Comment: I will! Thanks for the help and for clarifying things for me! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your state consists of `productTree` which is of type `Map<number, Node>`

```
export interface State {
  productTree: Map<number, Node>;
  errorMsg: string;
}
```

You are selecting `productTree` from the store.

```
this.categoryObs$ = this.store.select('productTree');
```

Hence, it will return `Map<number, Node>` and not an `Observable<State>`.

Instead, you should use `createFeatureSelector` to return the state, and then subscribe to it, like the below example.

```
 // reducers.ts
import { createSelector, createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

export interface FeatureState {
  counter: number;
}

export interface AppState {
  feature: FeatureState
}

export const selectFeature = createFeatureSelector<FeatureState>('feature');
```

and use this `selectFeature` in your Component

```
store.select(selectFeature).subscribe(store =. {
  this.counter = store.counter;
});
```

[Read about selectors from here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md)